# Error in traversing each cell of specific row of a table

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have table which is bound to JQuery DataTable.
I have a save button. At save button click, i want to traverse this html table and get each column value for specific row.

```
 function SaveData() {
    var txt = "";
    var strRows = "0,1,"
    var rows = "";
    var strData = "";
    var arrRows = new Array();
    if (strRows != null && strRows != "") {
        rows = strRows.substr(0, strRows.length - 1);
        arrRows = rows.split(',');
        // alert(arrRows);
        //alert(arrRows[0]);
        var result = arrRows.map(function (x) {
            return parseInt(x, 10);
        });

        for (var i = 0, l = result.length; i < l; i++) {
            //$(arrRows).each(function () {
            $('#example tbody tr').eq(result[i]).find('td').not(":first").each(function () {

                txt += $(this).text() + ",";
                //$("td:eq(1)").text();

            });
            strData += txt.substr(0, txt.length - 1);
            strData += ";";
            txt = "";
        }
        alert(strData);
    }
    //);

}
```

For 0 strRow, it is showing null values while for 1, it is showing column values for Row 0 and then null value for row 1.

Comment: is the first row using `th` for headers? if so you'll need to start from 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Please show your html for the table

Comment: I have tried 1 for Row Index but its not working.

Comment: Create a JsFiddle.net

Comment: <table id="example"  rules="all" style="width: 100%;"></table>

$("#example").dataTable();